# Default size of input split in Hadoop

Tags: hadoop

What is the default size of input split in Hadoop. As I know default size of block is 64 MB.
Is there any file in Hadoop jar in which we can see the default values of all such things ? like default replication factor etc. like anything default in Hadoop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remember these two parameters: mapreduce.input.fileinputformat.split.minsize and mapreduce.input.fileinputformat.split.maxsize.  I refer these as minSize, maxSize respectively. By default minSize is 1 byte and maxSize is Long.MAX_VALUE. The block size can be 64MB or 128MB or more.

The input split size is calculated by a formula like this during runtime:
**max(minSize, min(maxSize, blockSize)**

Courtesy: Hadoop:The definitive guide.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can see all these configurations in hadoop etc/conf folder.
There are various files : **core-default.xml, hdfs-default.xml, yarn-default.xml and mapred-default.xml**.
It contains all the default configuration for hadoop cluster which can be overridden as well.
You can refer following links:
https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r2.4.1/hadoop-project-dist/hadoop-hdfs/hdfs-default.xml
https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/current/hadoop-project-dist/hadoop-common/core-default.xml
https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/current/hadoop-mapreduce-client/hadoop-mapreduce-client-core/mapred-default.xml

And, if you have not defined any input split size in Map/Reduce program then default HDFS block split will be considered as input split.

Comment: Hi, Thanks for the answer. So, what is the default input split size ? I can't find that in these files.

Comment: Can you please give me the reference where you find that when we have not explicitly specified input split size then default HDFS block split will be considered as input split ?